# How to stop agent job failure log to event log

Tags: sql-server

I have a job in the notification tag, it is not configured to write to the event log in any scenario, but I still can find the log details when it failed.

Does anyone know why?

[Job Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkaz1.png)

[Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txmul.png)

Answer (score 0):

turns out, because I was lazy, instead of update the jobs, I updated msdb.dbo.sysjobs table directly, it does not pick the information correctly.